# Is it any good to make play game in zoom condition?

Tags: game-design, iphone, box2d, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

I'm developing a game with large obstacle and sprites(in cocos2d+box2d for iPhone), then after zooming out my sprites and layer (by increasing cameraZ), I make my game to play by user, which causes some problem in touch detection of dynamic objects.

Can it be said a good approach to work with? If No then what will be the solution to work properly(consider that I have traveled so far with this approach)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question entirely.

I'm guessing you're having problems because the Z of your camera changes and makes all your collision detection off.

If this is the case, you could try changing the FOV of the camera for the 'zoom' effect, this will remove any problems with the axis.

Comment: Well, please code, how to change the FOV.

Comment: In your call to `gluPerspective()`, the first parameter is the FOV, probably 45 or 60. The higher this number is, the more the camera 'zooms-in'.

Comment: `[self.camera setEyeX:0 eyeY:0 eyeZ:180];`(i'm using this line for zooming out, putting camera far from my sprites by increasing z)

Comment: Apparently you need to use the 'eye' property to scale instead of moving the camera.
`[self.camera setEyeX:x2 eyeY:y2 eyeZ:zoomFactor];` Where `zoomFactor` is your zoom factor :P

Comment: But i thought it is the only way to zoom out with proper touch detection(almost)

Comment: But I thought your touch detection didn't work properly? Did you try it?

Comment: yeah i did, so what should be the proper values for x2, y2 when zoomFactor=180

Comment: Try setting 0, 0.
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/9041, http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7522

Comment: I did! and arrived at initial..

Comment: Sorry I completely misunderstood your answer a while back :P
The second link I posted seems to give an explanation to calculating layer offsets, maybe this is what you need to do...

Comment: amm.. again code to calculate offset?